# How to apply for a new UK visitor visa after cancelling an earlier one?

Tags: visas, uk

Has anyone ever cancelled the UK visitor application after the biometric? Can you reapply after 1-2 years? Do they consider the withdrawn application?
Do you have to mention about it?  Is is the same like refusal?
Can you attach more documents and information with the new application depending on the circumstances at that time or you have to use the same thing?

Comment: ok thanks, so they don't consider the previous cancelled application? all I have to do if I want to apply is to send the application according to the circumstances at that time? so if my employment changes after 1 year and I join a different company by then, should I also mention my previous company and submit those documents too with the next application?

Comment: No, why would you refer to previous employment or submit old documents? See this guide https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cancelled application is *not* the same as a refusal. It will however still be in UKVI’s records, although IIRC the application does not ask about previously cancelled applications.

You can submit a new application any time after cancelling an earlier one; all information you submit should of course demonstrate your *current* circumstances and be consistent, where relevant, with any previous applications. This guide https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk explains what kind of documentation you should submit, and what *not* to submit.

Comment: ok thanks, so it is not considered as a refusal, so in my next application, I'll just briefly write that I withdrew the application, one quick question, do they consider the documents of the withdrawn application too? need I briefly mention about the documents I sent with the withdrawn application? cause there might not be enough space in that section or just forget about these things and mention only the current application and documents.

Comment: @traveller2 You want to make it as easy as possible for the ECO to review your application & documents and arrive at a decision. No-one will even have looked at your previous application. If you clutter up your new application with old information & pages of documents, you will just make the ECO’s life harder and possibly raise red flags in his/her mind. You don’t mention *why* you cancelled your earlier application, if you’re really worried about it include a brief explanation in the ‘extra comments’ section at the end. Otherwise keep it all focused, factual, and current

Comment: See this for some guidance (no affiliation) https://www.davidsonmorris.com/uk-visitor-visa-refusal/ BTW, if your concern is that your application is weak (few ties to home country, for example) then it might be best to wait until your circumstances are stronger, rather than risk a refusal. *Many people* worry/over-think their application, step back and objectively consider whether you meet the eligibility criteria and how best to demonstrate that. Then submit the best case you can

Comment: ok thank you so much for your help